# Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I run a query contains the following clause:

```
NOT REGEXP '.*[0-9]+|.*ح'
```

It works in Navicat as a MySQL client, but when I try through jdbc I get following error:

> Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp

If i remove the regular expression from the query it will be executed correctly, but I need this condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem is related to my connection string. It needs to set unicode parameters like the following:

```
autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```